# D3 'Drag' event fires even when mouse doesn't move

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag-and-drop, drag, mousemove

I've noticed that when I use `d3.drag().on('drag',...)`, it fires even when the mouse is not moved. Using the code snippet below (which I pulled from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46269674/how-frequently-is-d3-drag-event-triggered)), if I simply click and release I still see `drag event 1` in the console.

This is an issue because I want to be able to differentiate between a `dblclick` and a drag. I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931307/d3-differentiate-between-click-and-drag-for-an-element-which-has-a-drag-behavior) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075381/d3-mouse-events-click-dragend), but have been unable to get those solutions to work (it could be because those are old answers and I'm using D3 v4). I did notice that in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2EqA3/3/) in [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19942008/8791022), it's displaying the same issue: both a click event a drag event.

I figured that the `drag` event would only be fired if the mouse moved and then I could use it to set a flag that would mark it as dragging, not a doubleclick. However, this doesn't work if drag gets triggered on mouse press.

Very open to suggestions on this one as well as explanations as to why `drag` is behaving in this way. I realize this is browser dependent, so I am running Chrome 64.

```js
var count = 0;
d3.select("svg").call(d3.drag().on("start", function() {
  console.log("drag started")
}).on("drag", function() {
  ++count; 
  console.log("drag event " + count)
}).on("end", function() {
  count = 0;
  console.log("drag ended")
}))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 20% !important;}
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

So `d3.drag` has a [clickDistance()](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag#drag_clickDistance) function that you can call. This allows for a tolerance between a `mousedown` and a `mouseup` before a drag event is triggered and may well be what you're looking for.

```
const drag = d3.drag()
               .clickDistance(10)
               .on("start", () => { console.log("drag started"); })
               .on("drag", () => { console.log(`moved by ${d3.event.dx},${d3.event.dy}`); });
```

Normally this happens because you are actually moving the mouse slightly between a `mousedown` and a `mouseup`, but only very slightly. I've been looking at similar today, and probably about 25% of the time I move the mouse accidentally (using touch the problem gets worse).

Also to note because you've not really mentioned it but a `dblclick` event exists that you can subscribe to. Note that the order of events when using `dblclick` looks this (click isn't suppressed):

- click
- click
- dblclick

Answer (score 0):

I did come up with the following work around that solves the issue. Basically just save the mouse position on drag `start` and then check to see if the mouse has moved on drag `drag`.

While this works, I kind of assumed that `drag` would already be doing something like this, or that there would be a cleaner solution out there. Would love to know if someone has something better!

```js
var count = 0;
var dragStartPos = {};

d3.select("svg").call(d3.drag().on("start", function() {
  console.log("drag started")
  dragStartPos.x = d3.event.x;
  dragStartPos.y = d3.event.y;
}).on("drag", function() {
  if(d3.event.x != dragStartPos.x ||
     d3.event.y != dragStartPos.y) {
      ++count; 
      console.log("drag event " + count)
  }
}).on("end", function() {
  count = 0;
  console.log("drag ended")
}))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 20% !important;}
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is as an answer, I don't have enough rep to comment yet.

I don't see `d3.drag().on('drag',...)` being fired without moving the mouse. I get a `start` event on mousedown, and `end` event on mouseup and the `drag` event fires only when actually dragging. This is the behaviour on all the browsers I have tried so far (Chrome 63, FF 58, IE11). This seems to be inline with the [d3.drag API Reference](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag)

Comment: It actually works that way for me normally, but there are some times when it deviates and starts registering drag events even without mouse movement. I suppose this could be something with the mouse, but I've tried it with a click that's completely separate from a trackpad (so no movement is happening) and I still get it. But again, this only happens some of the time. Pretty weird behavior